# Java 2D ArrayList and sorting

Tags: java, arraylist, 2d

I need to sort a shopping list by the aisle the item is located for example:
[Bread] [1]
[Milk] [2]
[Cereal] [3]

I am planning to do this with ArrayList and was wondering how to make an 2D ArrayList
Bonus questions: any ideas on how to sort by the aisle number?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't you have a class that holds your item + aisle information? Something like:

```
public class Item {
  private String name;
  private int aisle;

  // constructor + getters + setters 
}
```

If you don't, consider making one - it's definitely a better approach than trying to stick those attributes into ArrayList within another ArrayList. Once you do have said class, you'll either need to write a [Comparator](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) for your objects or make 'Item' [Comparable](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) by itself:

```
public class Item implements Comparable<Item> {
  .. same stuff as above...

  public int compareTo(Item other) {
    return this.getAisle() - other.getAisle();
  }
}
```

Then all you do is invoke sort:

```
List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
... populate the list ...
Collections.sort(items);
```

Comment: would I have to make multiple objects or something, because the reason I thought of using an ArrayList was because I do not know how many items there would be

Comment: You'll have to create multiple Item instances, yes, and add them to ArrayList. `items.add(new Item("Bread", 1)); items.add(new Item("Milk", 2));`, etc...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sort an ArrayList of ArrayLists then you can use the [ColumnComparator](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/16/column-comparator/).

If you want to sort an ArrayList of your custom Object then you can use the [BeanComparator](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/23/bean-comparator/).

Answer (score 0):

I know the question was asked long ago but actually i had the same problem. If you dont know how many variables you would have on list but this is not a big number you could just implement comparator for every choose. eg

I have `ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>>` and want to sort it by column's and i know that the nested list consist of variable number of objects i can just implement comparator for every possible value:

```
public class SecondColumnComparator implements Comparator {

public static boolean isNumeric(String str) {
    try {
        Integer integer = Integer.parseInt(str);
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {

    if (isNumeric(((ArrayList<String>) o1).get(1))) {

        Integer firstInteger = Integer.parseInt(((ArrayList<String>) o1).get(1));
        Integer secondInteger = Integer.parseInt(((ArrayList<String>) o2).get(1));

        return firstInteger.compareTo(secondInteger);

    }
    if (((ArrayList<Object>) o1).get(1) instanceof String) {

        String firstString = ((ArrayList<String>) o1).get(1);
        String secondString = ((ArrayList<String>) o2).get(1);

        return firstString.compareTo(secondString);
    }

    throw new Exception();
}
```

}

And call this this way:

```
        switch (valueSelected) {
        case 0:
            Collections.sort(this.listOfLists, new FirstColumnComparator());
            break;
        case 1:
            Collections.sort(this.listOfLists, new SecondColumnComparator());
            break;
        case 2:
            Collections.sort(this.listOfLists, new ThirdColumnComparator());
            break;
        case 3:
            Collections.sort(this.listOfLists, new FourthColumnComparator());
            break;
        default:

    }
```

In every comparator just modifying `.get(x)` where x is number of collumn by which you want sort.

The `boolean isNumeric(String str);` function may be used because you cant store different type of objects on one list so I put the recognition of this to the comparator and parse String to any other type.

Remember that this `comparator` and its "calculations" are called to every single comparison made by algorithm so it is extremely inefficient... 
Despite this fact this is kind of sollution.