# How to Sort 2D ArrayList<String> by Only the First Element

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

**To avoid the duplicate claims**, I've looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1512366/java-2d-arraylist-and-sorting) post and it isn't exactly what I wanted. 
 Every other 2D ArrayList question involved `double` or `int` numbers; my question is about `Strings`.

#### What I'm doing

I have a 2D ArrayList, defined like this:

```java
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> namesAndNumbers = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
```

The idea is that the first item in every row of ArrayLists contains the names, and the rest of the columns in each row contains the phone numbers (unknown amount). Therefore I would like to avoid converting it to a regular array.

#### Sample

Let's say I've populated my ArrayList and I have this:

```java
{"Mike", "(805) 766-4920"}
{"Emily", "(705) 668-9292", "(705) 555-1060"}
{"James", "(605) 965-2000"}
```

I expect my **output** to be this:

```java
{"Emily", "(705) 668-9292", "(705) 555-1060"}    
{"James", "(605) 965-2000"}
{"Mike", "(805) 766-4920"}
```

I want to keep the numbers corresponding with the names, but simply sort the array by the name.

#### What answers I hope for

I'm hoping for a built-in function manipulation type of thing, but I'd be fine if someone created a sorting array method for me with an 2D ArrayList as the input. I haven't seen any question that answers this issue explicitly. *I will continue trying to come up with an answer myself as well*.

Comment: Why don't you use Collections in Java for this - i think that would be a perfect tool for your case, isn't it?

Comment: @harikris it is a nested ArrayList. Yes, I think Collections can work but I have no idea what to do with it.

Comment: If you used Collections, then sorting would become a breeze. Also, instead of Lists, if you used Sets, then you can avoid duplicate entries as well - all done automatically for you. It's not difficult to learn about Collections and Generics. May i suggest a reference book? Not sure if that will come across as promotional. I did not write this book. Just think it's an excellent resource. Authors are Kathy Sierra and Bert Bates. They have a chapter on Collections/Generics in their Head First Java book. HTH.

Comment: @harikris You can suggest it, but I probably won't read it to answer this question. I don't have the time currently to read it immediately. Possibly later, though. Thanks.

Comment: No problem. There's a working example in that chapter. Just so you know. For later use.

Comment: You should read and follow the accepted answer in that question, it still applies to your question, even though it's not an exact duplicate!

Comment: @RobinGreen I am going to try and follow that, but I would also like an answer on this question without going to the effort of creating another class.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use [`Collections.sort`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29) and provide a custom [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) where you compare the first element of each list, i.e the name :

```
List<ArrayList<String>> namesAndNumbers = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
namesAndNumbers.add(new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("Mike", "(805) 766-4920")));
namesAndNumbers.add(new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("Emily", "(705) 668-9292", "(705) 555-1060")));
namesAndNumbers.add(new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("James", "(605) 965-2000")));
Collections.sort(namesAndNumbers, new Comparator<ArrayList<String>>() {    
        @Override
        public int compare(ArrayList<String> o1, ArrayList<String> o2) {
            return o1.get(0).compareTo(o2.get(0));
        }               
});
System.out.println(namesAndNumbers);
```

Output :

```
[[Emily, (705) 668-9292, (705) 555-1060], [James, (605) 965-2000], [Mike, (805) 766-4920]]
```

Comment: I haven't seen other answer so simple. I'm glad I asked this question.

Answer (score 5):

Create a custom comparator:

```
final Comparator<List<String>> comparator = new Comparator<List<String>>() {
    public int compare(List<String> pList1, List<String> pList2) {
        return pList1.get(0).compareTo(pList2.get(0));
    }
};
final List<List<String>> lists = Arrays.asList(
    Arrays.asList("Mike", "(805) 766-4920"),
    Arrays.asList("Emily", "(705) 668-9292", "(705) 555-1060"),
    Arrays.asList("James", "(605) 965-2000")
);
Collections.sort(lists, comparator);
for (List<String> list : lists) System.out.println(list);
```

Comment: This solution also works. This also deserves +1.

Answer (score 1):

For diversity Why dont you just use a HashMap unless you want duplicate keys.
the key would be name and the value would be an ArrayList of numbers

```
String name="John";

ArrayList<String> phonenumbers=new ArrayList<String>();

phonenumbers.add("80925887");
phonenumbers.add("+166476654");

TreeMap<String, ArrayList> tm=new TreeMap<String, ArrayList>();

tm.put(name, phonenumbers);
```

Comment: This could be a good suggestion (I've never used HashMaps before), but this isn't an answer to my question. If you could, supplement this answer with a way to sort that HashMap.

Comment: Definitely buddy if your purpose is natural order you can use TreeMap instead of HashMap they both implements Map interface